# What is the minimum storage duration of S3 Standard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to estimate some costs in a service where we store objects in S3 for seconds to minutes before automatically deleting them after processing has completed.

I see that [the documentation](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/pricing/) states:

> S3 Standard-IA and S3 One Zone-IA storage have a minimum billable object size of 128 KB. Smaller objects may be stored but will be charged for 128 KB of storage at the appropriate storage class rate. S3 Standard-IA, and S3 One Zone-IA storage are charged for a minimum storage duration of 30 days, and objects deleted before 30 days incur a pro-rated charge equal to the storage charge for the remaining days. Objects that are deleted, overwritten, or transitioned to a different storage class before 30 days will incur the normal storage usage charge plus a pro-rated charge for the remainder of the 30-day minimum. This includes objects that are deleted as a result of file operations performed by File Gateway. Objects stored for 30 days or longer will not incur a 30-day minimum charge.

What about for S3 Standard? Prices are given per month, but I assume there's a minimum duration of some kind. If a 1 GB object exists in S3 for 5 seconds, am I only charged for 5/(30*24*60*60) or 0.00000192901 GB months?

If yes, what *is* the granularity? What if the object is there for 4.4s? 4.623s? *Note: I understand at this point it doesn't really matter, and I'm not going to making estimates from sub-second precision data. It's just interesting.*

Comment: The pricing page doesn't answer this, sadly. My understanding is that it's metered in TimeStorage-ByteHrs, the units are GB-Hours (technically GiB-hours) and the granularity is 1 hour.

Comment: The closest to answer I think you'll find is the documentation on the [frequency of the metrics](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/aws-usage-report-understand.html) that calls out TimedStorage as hourly, which matches with most other AWS services, unless otherwise specified.  So, I would assuming you pay for a min of an hour for any object.